# Market application not visible in GT-p3100 tab?

Tags: android, google-play

app do not appear in the Android Market when viewed from the Samsung Tab GT-P3100.

manifest file contains the following entries:

```
    <uses-sdk  android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

       <supports-screens
            android:anyDensity="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true"/>

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

How resolve the problem?give me any solution ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this below screen densities its working fine tablets.visible for play store also.

```
<!--all normal size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<!-- all large size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

<!-- all xlarge size screens -->
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
<screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

 <!-- Special case for Nexus 7 -->
 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
 <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
 <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
 <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="480" />

 <!-- all small size screens --> 
 <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
 <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" /> 
 <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" /> 
 <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
 <screen /> 

</compatible-screens>
```

Thank you very much for sharing information other developer forms ..thanks for all.